# Performing segue from didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a `performSegueWithIdentifier` in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, but it acts really weird. I have a tableView in the destination VC. When the cell is pressed, the segue fires and the viewDidLoad-method in the destination VC is triggered, but I have to tap the screen once more for the table view to start populating and for the VC to show.

This only happens when I perform the segue from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, not when I perform it from a button action.

I find this really weird, and can not figure out what is wrong.

**EDIT**: My `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`-method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let selectedCell:CategoryTableViewCell = self.categoriesTV.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell

     if selectedCell.categoryLabel.text == "VW" {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("chart", sender: self)
        self.datatypeToSend = "VW"
        self.chartTitleToSend = selectedCell.categoryLabel.text!

     }else if selectedCell.categoryLabel.text == "Porche"{

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("chart", sender: self)
        self.datatypeToSend = "Porche"
        self.chartTitleToSend = selectedCell.categoryLabel.text!

     }else if selectedCell.categoryLabel.text == "Lexus"{

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("chart", sender: self)
        self.datatypeToSend = "Lexus"
        self.chartTitleToSend = selectedCell.categoryLabel.text!

     }else if selectedCell.categoryLabel.text == "BMW"{

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("chart", sender: self)
        self.datatypeToSend = "BMW"
        self.chartTitleToSend = selectedCell.categoryLabel.text!


     }else if selectedCell.categoryLabel.text == "Toyota"{

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("chart", sender: self)
        self.datatypeToSend = "Toyota"
        self.chartTitleToSend = selectedCell.categoryLabel.text!

    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** The data-loading is not the problem, the problem occurs wether I'm loading the data or not, but only when the segue is triggered from my table view cells.

Comment: So the destination VC is in screen when you have to tap the second time?

Comment: Hi, please put some code so that people can see what is happening in your class.

Comment: @andrewbuilder Nope, the viewDidLoad-function is called, then I tap so all the other methods starts running and the VC finally shows when they are done.

Comment: Just throwing this out there..That giant if-else statement you have can be simplified to 3 lines of code.

Comment: Is the problem occurring because you're setting the data *after* you call `performSegue…`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the data before you perform the segue. Your if statement can also be simplified immensely. Try something like this for the method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let selectedCell: CategoryTableViewCell = categoriesTV.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CategoryTableViewCell

    // Simplified version of your if-else statement. Notice the data is set before performing the segue as well, which is important.
    datatypeToSend = selectedCell.categoryLabel.text ?? ""
    chartTitleToSend = selectedCell.categoryLabel.text ?? ""
    performSegueWithIdentifier("chart", sender: self)
}
```